# Nested if statement with multiple condition returns

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is return `"fizz"` when a number is divisible by `fizzNumber` and return `"fizzbuzz"` when a number is **divisible** by `fizzNumber` **AND** `buzzNumber`. I know I can just make an `&&` statement but I'm trying to use the least amount of code possible to achieve what I need. The problem here is that the nested if statement is unreachable, I'm assuming because the `if` statement ends after the return statement. How can I fix this so that this mimcks an && statement using a nested if while also returning both strings if the condition is true?

```
public String getValue(int n) {
    if (n % fizzNumber == 0) {
        return "fizz";
        if (n % buzzNumber == 0) {
            return "buzz";
        }
        return Integer.toString(n); // return the number itself as a String
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

```
public String getValue(int n) {
    if (n%fizzNumber==0) {
        if (n%buzzNumber==0) {
            // dividable by both fizzNumber and buzzNumber
            return "fizzbuzz";
        }
        // dividable by fizzNumber only
        return "fizz";
    }
    return Integer.toString(n);
}
```

or shorter (using terniary operator):

```
public String getValue(int n) {
    return (n%fizzNumber==0) ? (n%buzzNumber==0 ? "fizzbuzz" : "fizz") : Integer.toString(n);
}
```

Comment: Ah this makes total sense I was getting super confused with how to write it properly

Comment: this will not return `fizzbuzz` , look at OP again

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi: you're right, I fixed the answer now, thanks

Comment: would there be a simple way to print "fizzbuzz" by returning both "fizz" and "buzz" if both conditions were met?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
public String getValue(int n) {
    String ret = "";

    if(n % fizzNumber == 0) {
        ret += "fizz";
    }
    if(n % buzzNumber == 0) {
        ret += "buzz";
    }

    if(ret.equals("")) {
        ret = Integer.toString(n);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This can be optimized to:

```
public String getValue(int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if(n % fizzNumber == 0) sb.append("fizz");
    if(n % buzzNumber == 0) sb.append("buzz");

    return sb.length() == 0 ? Integer.toString(n) : sb.toString();
}
```

As you can see, this solution doesn't use nested if-statements.